# Replace numeric columns of dataset from other dataset

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to replace specifically the numerical columns of one dataset, with the numerical columns of a corresponding transformed dataset. How can I do it (without using code specific to the particular dataset)?

e.g. toy example from `mpg` in library `ggplot2`:

```
mpg0 <- mpg

set.seed(123)
mpg0[sample(nrow(mpg),70,replace=FALSE),3] <- NA
mpg0[sample(nrow(mpg),70,replace=FALSE),8] <- NA
mpg0[sample(nrow(mpg),70,replace=FALSE),9] <- NA

sampled <- sample(nrow(mpg),50,replace=FALSE)
mpg_test <- mpg0[sampled,]
mpg_train <- mpg0[-sampled,]

mpg_mean <- mpg_train %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise_if(is.numeric,mean,na.rm=TRUE)
temp1 <- mpg_test %>% left_join(mpg_mean, by = 'cyl')
```

Now I would like to replace the missing values in the numeric columns of `mpg_test` (columns `displ`, `cty`, `hwy`--there are no NAs in the other numeric columns) with the values in the corresponding column from the left-join. I can do it with

```
temp1 <- as.data.frame(temp1)
temp1[c(3,8,9)][is.na(temp1[c(3,8,9)])] <- temp1[c(12,14,15)][is.na(temp[c(3,8,9)])]
```

But that is specific to this dataset. Problem with `mutate_if` is that I don't know what function to put in. Is there a good general way of doing this, i.e. mutating the numeric columns to get the means, replacing NA with values in the same row from the corresponding left-joined columns?

(dplyr only please)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by altering your left join and using `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)

temp1 <- left_join(mpg_test, mpg_mean, by = "cyl")

temp1 %>% 
  mutate_if(is.integer, as.numeric) %>% 
  mutate(displ.x =
           case_when(
             is.na(displ.x) ~ displ.y,
             TRUE ~ displ.x
           ),
         cty.x =
           case_when(
             is.na(cty.x) ~ cty.y,
             TRUE ~ cty.x
           ),
         hwy.x =
           case_when(
             is.na(hwy.x) ~ hwy.y,
             TRUE ~ hwy.x
           )) %>% 
  select(-c(displ.y, year.y, cty.y, hwy.y)) %>% 
  rename(displ = displ.x,
         year = year.x,
         cty = cty.x,
         hwy = hwy.x)
```

Comment: see my updated post. ```temp1[c(3,8,9)][is.na(temp1[c(3,8,9)])] <- temp1[c(12,14,15)][is.na(temp1[c(3,8,9)])]
``` works and is simpler than this solution. I'm looking for a way to do it without specifying columns (just take all numeric columns)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `coalesce` :

```
library(dplyr)

mpg_test %>% 
  left_join(mpg_mean, by = 'cyl') %>%
  mutate(displ = coalesce(displ.x, displ.y), 
         cty = coalesce(displ.x, displ.y), 
         hwy = coalesce(hwy.x, hwy.y)) %>%
  select(-matches('\\.x|\\.y'))
```

Comment: see my updated post. ```temp1[c(3,8,9)][is.na(temp1[c(3,8,9)])] <- temp1[c(12,14,15)][is.na(temp1[c(3,8,9)])]
``` works and is simpler than this solution. I'm looking for a way to do it without specifying columns (just take all numeric columns)